# How to get variables in function name and getElementById

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop, do-while

hi i have a while loop:

```
var i = 0;

while(i < 20)
{
    function showi()
    {
        document.getElementById('tablei').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('hidei').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('showi').style.display = 'none';
    }

    function hidei()
    {
        document.getElementById('tablei').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('hidei').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('showi').style.display = 'block';
    }

 i++;

}
```

I want to know how I can get the i variable to show in the function names and getElementById.

Comment: Why would you want to create 20 functions that do the same thing when one function could do it all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    function show(i)
    {
        document.getElementById('table' + i).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('hide' + i).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('show' + i).style.display = 'none';
    }

    function hide(i)
    {
        document.getElementById('table' + i).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('hide' + i).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('show' + i).style.display = 'block';
    }
```

It's better to make one function, which you can call by for example "show(1)" or "show(42)"

Comment: Thankyou soo much been racking my brain for 2 days works perfectly XD

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the string concatenation operator "+".

That is, you can write:

```
'table' + i
```

and if you loop through different values of i, you will get the variable names you want:

```
table0
table1
table2
table3
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to create

```
show1(), show2(), show3(), etc...
```

with this loop? As it stands now, you're simply redefining the same function over and over.

You can't create dynamic function names, e.g.

```
function show + i() { ... }
```

is not possible. You can fake it with an eval call:

```
eval('function show' + i + '() { ... }');
```

but eval() is utterly evil and should NOT be used.

I'd suggest the following work-around, using an array:

```
show = [];
while(i < 20) {
   show[i] = function() { ... }
}

show[7](); // execute the #7 function
```

However, this is still very ugly. Why not simply pass `i` as a parameter?

```
function show(i) {
   document.getElementById('table' + i).style.display = 'block';
}
```

will do exactly what you want, and still be only one single function, not the 20+ you're trying to define.